# Getting app root in MVC controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to grab the physical path to the app root in an MVC project; I use this to serve from a repository that places its items on the file system.

Alternative, I could use Dependency Injection, but I'd have the same problem; I don't have a `Request` until someone calls an action, so I can't use `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a controller:

```
var root = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/"));
```